How can I demonstrate the limit of a probability function equals 1
How can I demonstrate that the limit of
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{{\sum_{i=0}^{10}[(-1)^i}\cdot\frac{10!}{i!\cdot(10-i)!}\cdot(10-i)^n]}{10^n}=1$$
This function came as a result when I was designing a formula to know the probability of getting all kind of tazoons based on the amount of number you bought. Being 10 the maximum amount of tazoons available (which can be any number really) and n the amount of tazoons bought.
The unexpanded form of the equation is
$${\frac{S(n,k)\cdot k!}{k^n}}$$
Where S(n,k) makes reference to Stiriling numbers of the second kind
For purposes of simplificating the demonstration part, I just set k as 10
I rationally know that the limit is 1 since probability cannot be higher than 100%, but I'm stuck at the demonstration part.
So far, I tried using L'Hospital rule. I have a little under a year learning calculus (and I'm self-taught) and I couldn't find any information in this kind of derivatives, so I tried calculating them individually.
In that case, both the result of the Sum from 0 to 10 of
$${(-1)^i}$$
and
$${\frac{10!}{i!\cdot(10-i)!}\cdot(10-i)^n}$$
Would be constants, therefore the derivative would be 0.
Then I tried taking the derivative of
$${{\sum_{i=0}^{10}(10-i)^n}}$$
and got:
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial n}{{\sum_{i=0}^{10}(10-i)^n}}= 2^nln(2)+3^nln(3)+4^nln(4)+...10^nln(10)$$ When $n>0$
Since in this formula $n>10$ (10 being replaceable by any other number) I assumed this wouldn't be a problem.
Then I took the derivative in the denominator which is simply
$$10^nln(10)$$
However, when I resolve:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{{
2^nln(2)+3^nln(3)+4^nln(4)+...10^nln(10)}}
{10^nln(10)}$$
I got $\infty$
Therefore, I realized that taking the derivatives individually was not the way to go, and that's the part I'm stuck at, any ideas on how can I continue/restart would be lovely

Could you provide the original probability question.

The original probability question was "What is the probability of me getting all different tazoons based on the amount of chip bags I buy if I know the amount of tazoons to get is k (in this case 10)" It sounds kinda dumb, but it was made by a friend of mine . I'm now stuck at the demonstration that the limit when n approaches infinity equals 1, which would be logical in any probability function.

It might help you to look up the “coupon collector’s problem “.

If you notice that $k^n$ is just the first term in your summation, i.e. the term with $i=0$, the rest is easy to tell.
You just need to prove that $\sum_{i=1}^{k}(-1)^k\binom{k}{i}\left(1-\frac{i}{k}\right)^n\rightarrow 0$.
$(-1)^k\binom{k}{i}$ are finite numbers,and $\left(1-\frac{i}{k}\right)^n\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ for any $i\neq 0$, so the sum above $\rightarrow 0$, and the original sum $\rightarrow 1$.
